# A pitfall appending class objects to a list in python

Tags: python, list

There is something not clear to me when appending an object to a python list.
Since the original code is too complicated and too long to be posted here, I worked out a minimal example to show the effect.
To explain it I managed to rework the code to function properly and to deliver the right result. But it required me a lot of time for debugging.
The reason because it happens is still not clear to me. So I'm very happy if you can *explain* me, why this happens.

Ok, let's go.

Here the working version of the code. At the end of it you can see, that it delivers an output and works as expected:

```
import numpy as np

class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.random.random()
    
    def move(self, value):
        self.x += value
        
p  = []
p2 = []

for _ in range(10):
    
    z = foo()
    z.move(4)
    p2.append(z)
    
p = p2
    
for i in range(10):
    print("Print x: {}".format(p[i].x))
```

Running the code I get the following output (which is after time different, since I call a random generator function). But it works!:

```
Print x: 4.18111236900313
Print x: 4.399997493230335
Print x: 4.594324823463079
Print x: 4.8205743285019045
Print x: 4.125578603746895
Print x: 4.430324972670274
Print x: 4.135255992051397
Print x: 4.9479568256336295
Print x: 4.789025666744436
Print x: 4.261426793909385
```

Now I show you the first version of the code, which caused me a lot of headache and a lot of anger. Please note, that I change slightly the second for loop because I found it more logical to me. I call the method `move()` directly and `append()` in one line, instead of two.
Here the version:

```
import numpy as np

class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.random.random()
    
    def move(self, value):
        self.x += value
        
p  = []
p2 = []

for _ in range(10):
    
    z = foo()
    p2.append(z.move(4))    # Here is the only change to the code!
    
p = p2

    
for i in range(10):
    print("Print x: {}".format(p[i].x))
```

But running this code I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x'
```

and then I discover that the lists *p* and *p2* have None as elements.
Why that?
I'm very happy to understand why...

**EDIT**

As suggested below I realized that the `move()` method doesn't return anything.

So I changed the code as follows:

```
import numpy as np

class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.random.random()
    
    def move(self, value):
        
        output    = foo()
        output.x += value
        
        return output      # <= Here the change
        
p  = []
p2 = []

for _ in range(10):
    
    z = foo()
    p2.append(z.move(4))
    
p = p2

    
for i in range(10):
    print("Print x: {}".format(p[i].x))
```

And it works!
Another important thing learnt today...

Comment: `foo.move` doesn't *return* `foo`; it returns `None` (implicitly, because there is no `return` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you may really be asking is why append stores what the method returns instead of the object. This is because when a method is used in assignment it's immediately executed and it's return value used in its place.

This is why you can pass methods to functions that are only designed to accept the value they return.

Example:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

def print_variable(variable_to_print):
    print(variable_to_print)

print_variable(square(2))
```

In this example print_variable doesn't receive square(2), it receives the value 4.

This is why move needs to return self in order to update x in place the way you're using it.

A simpler and possibly less controversial way of accomplishing this may be to simply execute this method at instantiation.

```
class foo(x=None):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.random.random()
        if x:
            self.x += x

    def move(self, value):
        self.x += value

p  = []
p2 = []

for _ in range(10):
    p2.append(foo(4))

p = p2
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a copy of the object first, helps to keep things in control (immutable simple data objects are more useful for maintainability, than mutable objects).

```
def move_immutable(self, value):
    c = copy.copy(self)  # add also "import copy" to the beginning of the file
    c.x += value
    return c
```

If you really want to keep things mutable, you might instead of the above, do this in the loop instead of p2.append(z.move(4)):

```
    z = foo()
    z.move(4)
    p2.append(z)
```

Comment: Must `import copy` be imported everytime when calling `move_immutable`??

Comment: All imports need to be in the beginning of the file, but it is there for the sake of clarity. I'll edit a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your `z.move()` method returns `None`.

If you want to change this behavior, change it to return `self`:

```
    def move(self, value):
        self.x += value
        return self
```

Comment: This "fixes" the issue, but violates a pretty reasonable convention that a method should either mutate its object or return a value, but not both.

Comment: "convention" citation please?